# Visual Studio project/solution properties lost after copying solution folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, project, solution

After exporting a project template and using it to set up a new project/solution (very simple C++ program with a few source files), I can close the solution, re-open it and all the properties I've set (ignoring certain warnings, selecting the CONSOLE subsystem) are intact.

However, if I manually copy the entire solution folder to a different location and then open the solution in the new location, those properties have disappeared.

Any idea how to copy a solution folder and have the custom properties I've set remain intact?

Comment: They are stored in the .vxproj file.  Assuming a copy accident is not exactly a great explanation, it is going to yell pretty loud when it can't find the .vxproj file.  Consider that the current Configuration or Platform selection isn't the same.  The two comboboxes at the top of the Properties dialog.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out the "Platform" selection -- it had changed on me. The original project Platform is "win32" but after copying the folder, the copy's Platform comes up as "Active(64)" for some mysterious reason. When I set it back to "Active(debug)", my properties reappear. So.... heh heh... is there anything I can do to keep it from arbitrarily changing the Platform selection on me when I clone the directory?? I'll try setting the Platform to Active(64) before the copy and then maybe it'll stay the same.

Comment: OK, I set the original platform to "All platforms", set the properties there, and they stuck in the copied folder. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.